# Объединение c++ и с# проектов

Tags: c#, c++

Доброго времени суток!
Есть готовый проект, написанный на C++ Builder. Пишется проект на Visual Studio C#. Подскажите начинающему как объединить функционал?

Comment: если хотите получить ответов, то опишите подробнее, что именно вы хотите. Вряд ли кому-то интересно это угадывть

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Я так понял что на C++ Builder написана некоторая библиотека (*.dll) функционал из которой Вы хотите использовать из C#. Если так, то Вам необходимо будет использовать PInvoke на C# (что это такое и как им пользоваться подробно написано в справке MSDN). Будьте внимательны с C++ Builder: при некоторых флагах компиляции вызвать функцию из Visual Studio будет не возможно! Смотрите чтобы при компиляции на C++ Builder стояла галочка Compatible with Microsoft Visual C++ (или что-то в этом духе, сейчас уже не вспомню). Успехов!